# When is a question asking for opinions considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, opinion-based

I just came across the following post ([Tensorflow 2.0 is getting harder to understand for senior tf developers, does anybody share the same feeling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55845317/tensorflow-2-0-is-getting-harder-to-understand-for-senior-tf-developers-does-an)) in my Triage queue and I was surprised that it was considered a Good Question despite the fact that it seems to be a combination of complaining about a change in design philosophy as well as asking for opinions on that design philosophy.

While I find this to be an interesting question, I'd like to know why it isn't considered 'Opinion-Based'. If someone could clarify this, that'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first comment on the question says this is off-topic. With 4 upvotes. It hasn't been closed as off-topic because of lack of traction I guess?

Comment: I failed an audit by marking it as Opinion Based, so I'm curious as to why it's considered a 'good question'.

Comment: "good question" just means "questions that got unilateral response". It's an automated system that looks at the response on the post. Because people didn't properly moderate this question, it slipped through....

Comment: Wasn't familiar with the rules on stackoverflow and didn't think anyone would be serious about this, I will close it. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: A different version of that question might have been on-topic. The question would probably be what changes are necessary to make opinionated question on-topic. Often there are interesting aspects that can be discussed rather objectively. Like instead of asking for judgements, asking for impacts.

Comment: [This post appears to have received some close votes / flags long before it was an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55845317/timeline#review_22846475). I've seen similar complaints in the past, and yet it seems trivial to avoid - **don't select questions for audit if they received close votes or flags at any point**, regardless of their current state.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It’s not a good on-topic question, at least not in the way it is written currently.

I am of the (perhaps somewhat controversial) opinion that many questions which *seem* opinion-based can, in fact, be carefully asked in a way that is constructive and suitable for Stack Overflow’s format. But doing this correctly is admittedly quite difficult, and requires that one is comfortable both with writing in English and with the nuances of Stack Overflow. I’ve been successful at this before, and I think questions about how to properly frame a question are a good use of the Meta site.

I thought this type of opinion-based-but-not question was going to be the focus of discussion in this Meta question just based on reading the title, but clearly that is not the case.

You found a low-quality question that is definitely “primarily opinion-based” and completely unsuitable for Stack Overfow. Somehow, it slipped through the cracks. Based on the first comment there, with several upvoted, there were users who accurately judged it as being off-topic, but not enough for a consensus to be reached. It also got popular enough to receive several upvotes on the question itself, presumably by other people who were interested in having the same discussion and less concerned about or familiar with Stack Overflow’s admittedly strict requirements.

Audit candidates are not selected manually by moderators, or even subject to review by moderators. (Although I’m beginning to think they should be.) Rather, they are chosen automatically by the system based on certain heuristics, like not being closed and having received several upvotes (the idea being, users must have looked at the question in order to upvote it, and they deemed the question appropriate and on-topic).

In certain cases, this heuristic-based approach falls flat on its face, and this was one of those cases. You can’t judge the frequency of false positives just based on their appearance on Meta, since that is subject to strong selection bias. False positives are, in fact, relatively rare. But when they do appear, they can be quite confusing and frustrating, as in this case.

I’ve dealt with that question by closing it, as it should have been long ago. That will remove it from the system as an audit candidate.

With the massive number of questions that Stack Overflow gets per day, it is not uncommon for many of them to fall through the cracks, effectively missing the closure they deserve.

That one has a rather depressing history. It got a vote to close by a trusted user soon after it was first asked—one minute after, in fact. That vote put it into the close vote review queue, but [no one ever acted on that review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/22846475), due to the massive backlog of posts in the review queue (around 10k at any given time).

After being in the close review queue for about 10 days, the close vote aged away and it was removed from the review queue, with no one ever acting on it.

However, despite the fact that no one ever saw it in the review queue, it actually picked up 3 other votes to close as “primarily opinion-based” from trusted community members with close-vote privileges. That’s a total of 4 close votes, one away from the threshold for closure.

Frankly, I think this points to a bug. That question’s jaded past *should* have been a strong enough signal to the system that the question was *not* clearly on-topic, even if it missed the threshold of actually getting closed.

The two downvotes it got *did* only come in today, almost certainly as a result of this Meta question, so the 5 upvotes that were sitting on it had been there since the early days. It’s understandable why the system might suspect that a +5 scored question with no downvotes was a good question, but I think accumulating 4 close votes should have been a sufficiently strong counter-signal, at least when selecting audit candidates. Those are supposed to be unambiguous.

The lack of downvotes is another systemic problem. I don’t have a good explanation for why 4 people would vote to close a question, yet *none* of them thought it worth a downvote.

**TL;DR**: You were right, the question was off-topic. I’ve handled it now as it should have been. Audits are broken, and not enough people downvote.

Comment: ...and that met my “answers typed out on mobile” quota for the day. Hope everyone enjoyed the show.

Comment: If you want users to downvote more, make the cost of downvoting lower. I'm sure there are a lot of users who think that because you lose reputation, downvotes should be used sparingly.

Comment: @Jolta It is free to downvote questions. Only answers take a point or two away from you. Those are in place to avoid people going around and revenge downvoting other answers to promote their own answer.

Comment: @Jolta that would only expose the underlying problem, people vote (or abstain) for the wrong reasons. Making downvoting have less of a reputation impact on the author of the content is not going to solve that root problem, it'll only make it easier for people to vote for the wrong reasons.

Comment: @Gimby I'm pretty sure a decent amount of users don't downvote because they don't want to "punish" others. Reducing the reputation impact would almost certainly reduce the number of people abstaining for that bad reason.

Comment: @krillgar I didn't know that downvoting questions was free! Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Gimby I didn't mean changing the reputation impact on the author of the content, I meant the impact on the voter (mistakenly believing it cost a point to downvote any content, see above).

Comment: @Dukeling Isn't 2 too small for a number already? Just compare it with +5 of a question upvote...

Comment: "Somehow, it slipped through the cracks." ...More like it joined the flood of questions that ought to be closed but aren't, which vastly outweigh the ones that either ought not be closed or are.

Comment: "*The lack of downvotes is another systemic problem*" if I'm casting a close vote, it's rare that I'd also downvote. This one I probably would have as it's too rant-y, but otherwise opinion-based questions aren't usually worth a downvote, IMO.

Comment: @user202729 For only that one factor, reducing the reputation impact seems likely to have a positive effect. Whether the overall effect would be positive or negative is up for debate. Downvotes on questions are IMO primarily to serve as a signal that it's bad and to ban people. The reputation loss is not required for either of those. I guess downvotes also prevents climbing reputation using mostly bad questions that get an upvote here and there, but those would probably lead to bans anyway. But I would definitely not reduce the reputation hit the poster takes for answers

Comment: @VLAZ Nearly all questions you would close are worth downvoting. Lacking usefulness and research go hand in hand with being close worthy. The downvote also communicates to other users that the question is poor before they click on it, allowing those looking for something to actually answer instead of something to moderate to spend their time elsewhere.

Comment: @jpmc26 I disagree. Particularly when voting for dupes, I regard this as answering OP's question. A lot of times I'm able to identify the dupe because I have more experience than OP or I might even know the secret incantations of how to conjure it up. SO is not that good at giving you relevant content if you search. So, a lot of times I'd VTC as dupe because I think that's genuinely what OP needs to look at not because "ur stupid for not knowing this!". Too broad or Unclear questions can be edited into shape, too. MCVE missing can be added.

Comment: @VLAZ I never called anyone stupid. I said they didn't spend the time to do their research. This often involves familiarizing yourself with the common terminology around a particular issue, and the asker couldn't find the answer because they failed to do so. SO is not here to give every user one-on-one instruction. Also, just because a question *could* be improved in no way means it shouldn't be downvoted. Most questions are never improved. It would be far better to downvote it and then check back later if you're concerned about that; the authors need the feedback that they need to improve.

Comment: @CodyGray Any chance you could provide some examples of opinion based questions that are a fit for Stack Overflow?

Comment: No, @CalvT, because I don't want to get into an extended debate about specific examples.